# Rendering video in play framework

Tags: iphone, scala, mobile-safari, playframework-2.4

I'm using play framework 2.4.6 for scala. My problem is that video that my app is can be opened/played/downloaded by chrome. safari on desktop downloads it. But safari browser on iphone/ipad can not play it. I want my web app to render video in such way that safari browser on iphone/ipad.

**Note:**
I converted video properly for apple devices, even more: when I embed video link to HTML file and copied it to xampps htdocs folder with Apache server, safari on iPhone can play it without any problem.
Here are my routes file content:

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index
GET     /videos/:name               controllers.Videos.stream(name:String)
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

Videos.scala controller:

```
class Videos extends Controller{
  def stream (name:String)= Action {
    //video files stored locally in 'videos' folder in order to use it on production mode also
    val file = new java.io.File(Play.application().path()+"/videos/"+name)
    import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    val fileContent: Enumerator[Array[Byte]] = Enumerator.fromFile(file)
    Result(
      ResponseHeader(200, Map(
        CONTENT_LENGTH -> file.length.toString,
        CONTENT_RANGE -> s"bytes */${file.length.toString}",
        ACCEPT_RANGES -> "bytes",
        CONTENT_TYPE -> "video/mp4",
        PRAGMA -> "public",
        CONTENT_TRANSFER_ENCODING -> "binary",
        CONTENT_DISPOSITION -> "attachment"
      )),
      body = fileContent
    )
  }
}
```

my index test page:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>myvideo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video controls="true"
        poster="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/myvideo.jpg")" style="width:auto;" title="myvideo">
            <source src="@routes.Videos.stream("myvideo.mp4")" type="video/mp4"/>
            <source src="@routes.Videos.stream("myvideo.m4v")" type="video/mp4"/>
            <source src="@routes.Videos.stream("myvideo.3gp")" type="video/3gp"/>
            <source src="@routes.Videos.stream("myvideo.mov")" type="video/mov"/>
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

Even if I'm writing "http://*mypcipaddress*:9000/videos/myvideo.mp4" in safari browsers address bar. It shows that player can not play video:
[smartphone screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QX7WO.png)

Please anyone help me.

Comment: Safari on iphone can not play my video, thats the problem

Comment: Are you sure that the video is a mp4 file rather than a ogg/webm file. I know that safari might have issues with decoding those video formats.

Comment: I solve this problem, by copying video for Apache's public folder on VPS programmatically in my Controller, then by adding link to this video in my View, so that video rendered not by Play, but by Apache itself

Answer (score 0):

For me, Play Framework's [range request support](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/AssetsOverview#Range-requests-support) solved this (2.5.x). This is due to Iphone's and Ipad requesting certain parts, hence ranges.

> Assets controller automatically supports part of RFC 7233 which
>   defines how range requests and partial responses works. The Assets
>   controller will delivery a 206 Partial Content if a satisfiable Range
>   header is present in the request. It will also returns a
>   Accept-Ranges: bytes for all assets delivery.

Doing so, the following code:

```
def video(videoId: Long) = Action { implicit request =>
    val videoFile = getVideoFile(videoId)   
    RangeResult.ofFile(videoFile, request.headers.get(RANGE), Some("video/mp4"))
}
```

.. would also set the accept-ranges and results (206 and 200), allowing Safari to retrieve the file.